# Вставка DataSet в БД, где есть связи между таблицами

Tags: c#, .net

Что-то искал искал я примеры, но так и ничего не нашел, а может плохо искал...=(

В общем, допустим у меня есть таблицы в БД, которые имеют связи между собой => вставка и все такое должна выполняться в определенном порядке + нужно еще обновлять ParentId в зависимых сущностях на те, которые получились после вставки главной записи.

Я создаю DataSet на клиенте, делаю такие же связи и все такое. Наполняю данными и все такое.

А дальше, как это все пулнуть в БД. Как я понимаю, нужно хитрые запросы на INSERT написать в DataAdapter или можно сделать так, что бы это само разрулилось?

Интересует решение штатными либами фреймворка.

Comment: БД - понятие растяжимое, что именно за БД? А вообще штатная либа на самом деле внештатная, и называется Entity Framework.

Comment: Есть способ сгенерировать команды `insert, update, delete` автоматически: [Generating Commands with CommandBuilders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders), но он работает только для одиночных несвязанных таблиц. Так что придётся писать запросы ручками.

Comment: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) - ссылка в помощь.

Comment: [How to: Create and configure datasets in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-datasets-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) - если создавать датасет в дизайнере, то там можно задать правила Cascade для отношений.